# Opencv 3.0.0 , C++, Visual Studio 2015 - error in finding contours and ConvexHull

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to write a program that can create a polygon(of any number of sides) around a certain object and find the polygon's centroid . For this purpose, I opted to use the convexhull and findContours functions. In the following program, you get two windows. One window contains the trackbars for changing the HSV and morphogical values of the filter and the other contains the filtered image. After filtering the image and obtaining a binary image, you have to click 'c' to find the contours and then 'h' to find the convexhull. Filtering the image and performing morphological operations isn't a problem. The main problem is finding contours.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv2\video\background_segm.hpp>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//functions prototypes
void on_trackbar(int, void*);
void createTrackbars();
void showimgcontours(Mat &threshedimg, Mat &original);
void toggle(int key);
void morphit(Mat &img);
void blurthresh(Mat &img);

//function prototypes ends here

//boolean toggles

bool domorph = false;
bool doblurthresh = false;
bool showchangedframe = false;
bool showcontours = false;
bool showhull = false;

//boolean toggles end


int H_MIN = 0;
int H_MAX = 255;
int S_MIN = 0;
int S_MAX = 255;
int V_MIN = 0;
int V_MAX = 255;

int kerode = 1;
int kdilate = 1;
int kblur = 1;
int threshval = 0;


int main(void)
{
    createTrackbars();
    on_trackbar(0, 0);

    Mat frame, hsvframe, rangeframe;
    int key;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while ((key = waitKey(30)) != 27)
    {
        toggle(key);
        cap >> frame;
        flip(frame, frame, 180);
        cvtColor(frame, hsvframe, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        inRange(hsvframe, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX,    V_MAX), rangeframe);

        if (domorph)
            morphit(rangeframe);

        if (doblurthresh)
            blurthresh(rangeframe);

        if (showcontours)
            showimgcontours(rangeframe, frame);

        if (showchangedframe)
            imshow("Camera", frame);
        else
            imshow("Camera", rangeframe);

    }

}


void on_trackbar(int, void*)
{//This function gets called whenever a
 // trackbar position is changed
    if (kerode == 0)
        kerode = 1;
    if (kdilate == 0)
        kdilate = 1;
    if (kblur == 0)
        kblur = 1;
}
void createTrackbars()
{
    String trackbarWindowName = "TrackBars";
    namedWindow(trackbarWindowName, WINDOW_NORMAL);
    createTrackbar("H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Erode", trackbarWindowName, &kerode, 31, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Dilate", trackbarWindowName, &kdilate, 31, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Blur", trackbarWindowName, &kblur, 255, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Thresh", trackbarWindowName, &threshval, 255,    on_trackbar);

}

void morphit(Mat &img)
{
    erode(img, img, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(kerode, kerode)));
    dilate(img, img, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(kdilate, kdilate)));
}
void blurthresh(Mat &img)
{
    //medianBlur(img,img,kblur%2+3+kblur);
    blur(img, img, Size(kblur, kblur), Point(-1, -1), BORDER_DEFAULT);
    threshold(img, img, threshval, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
}
void toggle(int key)
{

    //toggle line start
    if (key == 'm')
        domorph = !domorph;
    if (key == 'b')
        doblurthresh = !doblurthresh;
    if (key == 'r')
        showchangedframe = !showchangedframe;
    if (key == 'c')
        showcontours = !showcontours;
    if (key == 'h')
        showhull = !showhull;
    //toggle line end
}

void showimgcontours(Mat &threshedimg, Mat &original)
{
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    int largest_area = 0;
    int largest_contour_index = 0;

    findContours(threshedimg, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    vector<vector<Point> >hull(contours.size());

    //find a hull for each contour
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false);
    }

    //this will find the largest contour
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++) // iterate through each contour. 
    {
        double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);  //  Find the area of each contour
        if (a>largest_area)
        {
            largest_area = a;
            largest_contour_index = i;                //Store the index of   the largest contour
        }

    }
    //search for the largest contour has end

    if (contours.size() > 0)
    {
        drawContours(original, contours, largest_contour_index, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy);
        //if you want to show every contour, use the following
        //drawContours(original,-1, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy);
        if (showhull)
            drawContours(original, hull, largest_contour_index, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, hierarchy);
        //if you want to show every hull(s), use the following
        //drawContours(original,-1, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it always triggers a breakpoint in the vector class templates(somewhere in `void Tidy()`) whenever I try to run the findcontours() function. A dialog box pops up and displays the following message:

"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9374CD328 (ucrtbase.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/1zvdf1t.png]

Then the dialog box redirects me to the vector class templates and displays a breakpoint in the 7th line of the below segment.

```
void _Tidy()
    {   // free all storage
    if (this->_Myfirst() != pointer())
        {   // something to free, destroy and deallocate it
        this->_Orphan_all();
        _Destroy(this->_Myfirst(), this->_Mylast());
        this->_Getal().deallocate(this->_Myfirst(),
            this->_Myend() - this->_Myfirst());
        this->_Myfirst() = pointer();
        this->_Mylast() = pointer();
        this->_Myend() = pointer();
        }
    }
```

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/2yx0p37.png]

Is this a problem with the findContours function or the vector class or something completely different?

Comment: [csumike](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5572856) thinks this may be caused by a known bug: http://code.opencv.org/issues/4452#note-3

Comment: ([I don't think his answer should have been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10236232), as it provided what appeared to be a useful and valid answer. Unfortunately, being a new user and starting your post with 'i have the same problem' is likely to get your answer deleted, as it's a common mistake for new users to use the answer box for non-answers. Such is how reviews go, sometimes.)

Answer (score 5):

It is probably a simple linking problem.

If you are compiling in **Debug** mode, the linker needs the Input Variables `opencv_world310d.lib` not the `opencv_world310.lib` (notice the `d` before the dot).

Only when you compile the **Release** mode you have to type in the `opencv_world310.lib`.

I had the same problem. Cost me a day to figure out.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same my case. (opencv 3.0)
I tried this, then findcontours() works well.

I think, you already input information as follows..
Linker --> Input (입력) --> Additional Dependencies

opencv_world300d.lib
opencv_world300.lib
opencv_ts300d.lib
opencv_ts300.lib

There arent't edited library, I was just align it (300d.lib -> 300.lib)
and apply! and it works well!

Answer (score 0):

according to this :
[Returning from function crashing, only after a certain point in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349157/returning-from-function-crashing-only-after-a-certain-point-in-the-code)

and my own experience (unfortunately) compiling the program in vs 2013 instead of 2015 or just changing the platform toolset to (v120) was enough for me to fix the bug