# Returning from function crashing, only after a certain point in the code

Tags: c++, function, opencv, crash, return

I am having trouble figuring out why my function is crashing my program when I return from it. I did a bit of debugging and fond the moment where returning from the function causes it to crash.

```
void Find_contour()
{
//VAR
double threshold_val = 128;
int n_erode_dilate = 1;
Mat m = img_complete.clone();

cvtColor(m, m, CV_RGB2GRAY);
blur(m, m, Size(5, 5));
threshold(m, m, threshold_val, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
erode(m, m, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), n_erode_dilate);
dilate(m, m, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), n_erode_dilate);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Point> points;

    //returning here is safe******

findContours(m, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    //returning after here crashes******

for (size_t i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++) {
        Point p = contours[i][j];
        points.push_back(p);
    }
}


vector<vector<Point>> contours_poly(contours.size());
vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
vector<Point2f> center(contours.size());

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
}

//drawContours(img_contour, contour, idx, colors[idx % 4]);

for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
{
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, CV_RETR_LIST, 0, Point());
    rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
}

}
```

Here is the function, I have labelled where the it is safe to return and where it crashes, so I am assuming it has something to do with my vectors there.

I may just be missing something basic, which is making it hard for me to look up, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Hey I have narrowed it down `findContours`. stepping through the code, returning at a safe spot takes me to `inline void Mat::release(` function, while anywhere after `findContours` takes me something commented as `// TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Destroy_range`. which then goes to `void deallocate` which at this points causes a break in my program. and has a message.

*Unhandled exception at 0x51995042 (ucrtbase.dll) in Image detection 2.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.*

I would also like to add that this error only occurs when the function returns or ends, and there are no errors during `findContour`.

I am fairly new to this whole process, and am very appreciative of everyone's help.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check running ? Probably, with debugger and by observing values, you will find why it crashes

Comment: Also, to iterate on vector, you can use iterator : for (vector<vector<Point> >::iterator it = contours.begin() ; it != contours.end(); ++it) for (vector<Point>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2) points.push_back(*it2);

Comment: You must have got some kind of message along with the crash. Even if you don't understand what it means, somebody else might. Add it to the question.

Comment: Your last two `for` loops use `contours.size()` as the limiting factor, but you're referencing `boundRect`'s using the index `i`.  Shouldn't you (at the very least) write the loop to ensure there is a valid `boundRect[ i ]`?

Comment: Stackoverflow? How many `Points` are in `vector<vector<Point> > contours` after running `findContours(m, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `boundRect` is initzialized with `contours.size()`. So this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Simon Sorry, I am not 100% sure if im looking at the right thing, in my locals, I see `contours {size=1}` and it is in red(although it was in red before the `findContours`). Branching it out under it there is `[0] {size=960}`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have updated with the message the pops up when it breaks.

Comment: @Garf365 it is hard to observe the values, as it only breaks when the function ends/returns rather then when the error is actually happening. if that makes sense. So I am not exactly sure what I am looking for.

Comment: Seems like you are not the first one to encounter this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160401/opencv-3-0-0-c-visual-studio-2015-error-in-finding-contours-and-convexhul

Comment: @J.Doe Are you using VS2015? Do you have access to another Visual Studio or even a different compiler to test if it works there? It may be a bug in OpenCV in combination with VS2015...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, there is a bit of a compatibility issue with OpenCV 3.0.0 and Visual Studio 2015.

I have tried it with Visual Studio 2013 and everything works perfectly.

thank you to those who helped, and thank you to @Simon Kraemer for suggesting this.