# Unhandled exception in OpenCV feature matching

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I'm now working on feature matching, and I wrote these codes below.

```
void CLPS::ExtractKeyPoints()
{
    vector<DMatch> init_matches;

    ULONGLONG timer;
    timer = GetTickCount64();

    Ptr<BRISK> fd_a = BRISK::create(20);
    fd_a->detectAndCompute(S, Mat(), spoints, desc_s, false);
    fd_a->detectAndCompute(T, Mat(), tpoints, desc_t, false);
    timer = GetTickCount64() - timer;
    cout << "Detect and compute: " << timer << " milliseconds complete. Output: " << spoints.size() << " points. \n";

    timer = GetTickCount64();
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher = FlannBasedMatcher(cv::makePtr<cv::flann::LshIndexParams>(10, 32, 2));
    matcher.match(desc_s, desc_t, init_matches);
    timer = GetTickCount64() - timer;
    cout << "Matching time: " << timer << " milliseconds complete. " << endl;

    Point2f spt, tpt;
    int num_matches = 0;

    vector<DMatch>::iterator iter_matches;
    coord_matches.create(1, 3, CV_32FC1);
    Mat cm_row;
    cm_row.create(1, 3, CV_32FC1);

    if (!init_matches.empty())
    {
        for (iter_matches = init_matches.begin(); iter_matches != init_matches.end(); ++iter_matches)
        {
            spt = spoints[iter_matches->queryIdx].pt;
            tpt = tpoints[iter_matches->trainIdx].pt;

            if (std::abs(spt.y - tpt.y) < VERTICAL_EPSILON && tpt.x - spt.x < upperbound && tpt.x - spt.x > lowerbound)
            {
                num_matches++;
                coord_matches.reserve(num_matches);
                cm_row.at<float>(0, 0) = spt.x;// 与 CV_32FC1 对应
                cm_row.at<float>(0, 1) = spt.y;
                cm_row.at<float>(0, 2) = tpt.x - spt.x;
                coord_matches.push_back(cm_row);
            }
        }

        cout << coord_matches.rows << " matches found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "No match is found. Validate your source data or report to us if there is a bug. " << endl;
    }
}
```

Then I just call it like this:

```
CLPS lps;
lps.ExtractKeyPoints();
```

However, it triggers an exception with following message when this function is returning:
**Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC0797D328 (ucrtbase.dll) in dars_lps.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.**
where `dars_lps.exe` is my application name. Then the program jumps to some destructors in `<vector>`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1 Update 1, and my OpenCV version is 3.1. I have confirmed that I'm linking to correct version of library files (i.e. vc14).
I was once working on Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 SP1, OpenCV 2.4.9, but it never reported such an exception.
I know this question may be similar to some other questions elsewhere (e.g. [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/74771/findcontours-exception/) on OpenCV site), occuring when calling different functions, but all of them are staying unsolved. I suspect that the problem lies in BRISK or FlannBasedMatcher, but I can't comment out those code (or this function will be virtually empty, and obviously, no more exceptions).
I also noticed that the problem was rising up after OpenCV 3.0 was released, and most of the similar problems happen in newer versions of Visual Studio or Windows. Both 64-bit and 32-bit platforms have this kind of problems. There does exist a report of such problem in Visual Studio 2015 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349157/returning-from-function-crashing-only-after-a-certain-point-in-the-code), but it was OpenCV 3.0 that is used, when there were **no** library built for Visual Studio 2015 yet.
Is it still a bug to be fixed or an error of syntax by myself?

Comment: This question is closed since I don't need an answer any more.