# Fatal program exit requested (ucrtbase.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, dll, crt

I built an open-source software named [OpenARK](https://github.com/augcog/OpenARK) using OpenCV3.2.0, Visual Studio 2015, and PCL 1.8 on Windows 10 64 bit along with a PMD camera that uses PMD SDK. After the build is done completely with no error, I get the following error when trying to Start Without Debugging:

```
ucrtbase.dll fatal program exit requested 0x00007FF86C8AEA1E
```

How can this error be fixed and what is causing it? OpenCV3.2.0 has the libraries built for VC14 so that doesn't seem to cause the issue. Debugging the issue doesn't provide further information.

Here's a more thorough log:

```
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\openark_mona\OpenARK\x64\Release\OpenARK-SDK.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_common_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_search_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_filters_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_features_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world320.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_segmentation_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_visualization_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\pmdsdk\lib\pmdaccess2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_kdtree_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_octree_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_sample_consensus_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_ml_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_io_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.14393.447_none_0d5aa7fbb6d35646\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\concrt140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.0\bin\pcl_io_ply_release.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\OpenNI2\Tools\OpenNI2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvoglv64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winsta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenARK-SDK.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x1844 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF86C8AEA1E (ucrtbase.dll) in OpenARK-SDK.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF86C8AEA1E (ucrtbase.dll) in OpenARK-SDK.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF86C8AEA1E (ucrtbase.dll) in OpenARK-SDK.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

The program '[960] OpenARK-SDK.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here's copy of exception:

```
    >   OpenARK-SDK.exe!__scrt_unhandled_exception_filter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * const pointers) Line 75 C++
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF86C8AEA1E (ucrtbase.dll) in OpenARK-SDK.exe: Fatal program exit requested.
    ucrtbase.dll!00007ff86c8aea1e() Unknown
```

[image][image]

Update: I have seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35453129/2414957 I am using Release in x64 mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run in debug first. Make sure that you have enable "Break when thrown" for std::exceptions in exceptions settings and you'll see what throws exception that causes the exit:

[image]

Note, that you may as well do that in release, but in general you'll have better luck when debugging debug builds. In debug you'll need to link to `opencv_world320d.lib`

You may also try to wrap your main with try/catch to see what exception is thrown.

```
try {
    // your code...
} catch(std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The person who has developed the software has mentioned to run in release and x64

Comment: @MonaJalal you can also debug in release, just enable exception settings. You should also have OpenCV src code most likely, otherwise you won't be able to see code that throws that exception.